# Why is Visual Studio on Compiler Explorer ignoring the Exception Model setting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, compiler-explorer

When I try to use the `/EHs` flag in [a Compiler Explorer testcase](https://godbolt.org/z/Md2g7J) (to "enable" exceptions passing through `extern "C"` functions), VC++ 19.22 seems to be ignoring it, based on it still kicking out a C5039 and not actually changing the code.

What am I missing? Have I forgotten another switch or something?

- Base case cmdline: `/O1 /EHsc /Wall /wd4571`
- Test case cmdline: `/O1 /EHs /Wall /wd4571`

Comment: SO you've found/fixed the problem … BUT, do you now get different code generated? (The stuff I tried yesterday on your related issue always gave the same generated ASM, no matter what use of /EH I tried.)

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica I haven't fixed the problem yet sadly; I'm not sure there's a way to override that flag, so I've asked Matt whether he can make it conditional or something. FWIW, I was able to prove externally that the approach works ... _but_ I've yet to produce a useful self-contained testcase online. This question was generated by my getting back into that - watch this space :)

Answer (score 4):

Ah, looks like Compiler Explorer sets the exception model itself, and this is taking precedence.

[image: Screenshot of the culprit]

Comment: Good ol' freehand red circles!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Really? All I can see is `Screenshot of the culprit`. (Damn company firewall.) ;-) (Although, I'm happier to see this than the usual _Enter image description here._)

Comment: @Scheff Is [this archive.org screenshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20191126124038/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050839/why-is-visual-studio-on-compiler-explorer-ignoring-the-exception-model-setting/59050911?noredirect=1) allowed? ;)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Nope. Same issue: Content blocked. (Thanks for your effort but, please, don't waste your time. I'm used to it.)

Comment: @Scheff Blimey!

Comment: @Scheff I tried converting it to SVG for you, but [it didn't go very well](https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ptqbk/)

Comment: It doesn't look like Compiler Explorer anymore. However, I consider to print it and add it to my wall decoration in office. (Currently, most of the wall is covered with XKCD comics...)

Comment: Warm thanks. You already got my votes to pay back for your effort. I will ask our engineers whether I could (ab)use their A0 plotter...

Comment: @Scheff Sounds good  Be sure to take a photo and put it on, er, imgur... okay perhaps an ASCII art version then